# Difficulty answering an augmented matrices question

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

How would I express these equations as an augmented matrix? I know how to convert simply equations to an augmented matrix but the added $k$ and $z$ are confusing me.

$x + 2y - z = -3$

$3x + 5y + kz = -4$

$9x + (k+13)y + 6z = 9$

Comment: $z$ is just a variable like $x,y$ and the terms involving $k$ are coefficients which have to be treated in the same way as other coefficients. Now can you form the matrix?

Answer (score 1):

$k$ may be just a  constant.

You can write it as,

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & -1 \\ 3 & 5 & k \\9 & k+13&6\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-3\\-4\\9\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: where did the 2 in the first row come from or was that just a typo?

Comment: $2$ is the co-efficient of $y$

Comment: ah sorry It was a typo on my end